# Can I have Atom IDE automatically check for camelcase?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, camelcasing

I just lost 1.5h of time trying to debug a piece of code I wrote only to find I had mistyped clickData.menuItemID instead of clickData.menuItemId

Is there a plugin or better IDE that automatically can check that I've named my variables or properties etc like this in the proper camelcase? I find this type of issue hinders me often and I can't always see the mistake when I'm trying to debug it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set ESLint rule to identify functions are camelcase or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317406/how-to-set-eslint-rule-to-identify-functions-are-camelcase-or-not)

Comment: That's the job of a linter, not of the editor - although you'll certainly find a plugin to run the linter of your choice directly in atom.

Comment: alternatively, you can rely on atom's autocomplete.